# How to limit the number of digits in react-currency-input

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to allow limited number of digits in my `react-currency-input` component. Below is my code to generate the currency input, which is working fine. but it is allowing unlimited number of digits in it. Could some one please help me to allow only a limited number of digits?

```
<CurrencyInput 
  value="" 
  prefix="$"
  precision="2"
  ref="myinput"
  onChangeEvent={this.handleChangeEvent}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `maxLength` for the input (the length includes prefix etc so take that into account):

```
<CurrencyInput maxLength={10} />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, riwu! it works exactly what i wanted to do.